# How to find the optimal angles to direct a light beam?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, symmetry, reflection

I have an optical system that looks as follows:
[image: Sketch of optical system]
[Sketch of optical system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaHzK.png)

There is a light beam shining on a mirror with a direction that is controlled using $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as shown in the sketch. The two green planes are parallel detector planes on which the incoming light beam can be registered (Points $R_1$ and $R_2$). The goal is to steer the beam such that it goes exactly through $P_{1,goal}$ and $P_{2,goal}$ . It can be done iteratively, however I want to calculate the optimal $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the beam fulfills this condition. The main issue is that I don't know much about the optical system:

- The distances between the two green detector planes are not known
- The absolute values of angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not known (the relative angles are known however!)
- The location of the light source $S$ is not known

However, I know the position of $P_{1,goal}$ and $P_{2,goal}$ on their corresponding plane and I know $R_1$ and $R_2$ (as this is measured by the detector). Moreover, whenever $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is altered, I know by how much.

I tried to approach this problem by using linear algebra. I could come up with the following forumlas that hold for my sketch (where $i=(1,\dots,N)$ denote the different points for each beam I record):

$$\tag1\overrightarrow{P_i^*}= \overrightarrow{S}-\frac{(\overrightarrow{S}-\overrightarrow{P})\cdot\overrightarrow{n_d}}{\overrightarrow{n_d}\cdot\overrightarrow{n_{s,i}}}\cdot\overrightarrow{n_{s,i}}
$$
$$\tag2
\overrightarrow{n_{r,i}}=\overrightarrow{n_{s,i}}-2\cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{n_{d}}\cdot\overrightarrow{n_{s,i}}}{\left \| \overrightarrow{n_{d}} \right \|^2}\cdot\overrightarrow{n_{d}}
$$
$$
\tag3
\overrightarrow{n_{r,i}}=\overrightarrow{R_{1,i}}-\overrightarrow{P_{i}^*}=\overrightarrow{R_{2,i}}-\overrightarrow{P_{i}^*}$$
However, in my opinion there are too many unknowns in the formulas to calculate anything properly. Hence, I am looking for different approaches towards tackling this problem. I can record as many $R_1$ and $R_2$ and their corresponding angles as I want, so I think starting from this I should be able to find a unique solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I posted the diagram, but please type the geometric formulas, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  The practice on this site is to avoid posting images where possible, because images cannot be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I revised the formulas now into LaTeX

Comment: Are the detector planes known to be parallel, as suggested by the diagram? And is the line between  the two detector points actually perpendicular to the planes, as suggested?

Comment: Why not try to identify the system parameters with the data you have? The set of measures $\{\alpha_k,\beta_k,\delta R_{1k},\delta R_{2k}\}$ can furnish us some clues...

Comment: @Cesareo I cannot provide data since I cannot do measurements on the actual system yet (this problem is part of an algorithm I would like to have ready as soon as the setup is available). How would go about identifying system parameters from $\{\delta\alpha_k, \delta\beta_k, R_{1,k}, R_{2,k}\}$? I think if you have a general idea how this could be done, actual data is not required (Using variables instead would also work)

Comment: @JohnHughes The two detector planes are parallel indeed. The line between the two detector planes $P_{2,goal}−P_{1,goal}$ is perpendicular to the plane. I chose the coordinate system with origin in $P_{1,goal}$ since it seemed most reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

To have an account over the known facts.

Given a mirror plane $\Pi_m\to (p-p_m)\cdot\vec n_m=0$, the incident ray support line $L_1\to p = S+\lambda\vec n_S$ the reflected ray line support $L_2\to p=p^* + \mu\vec n_r$ and the detector planes $\Pi_1\to (p-p_1)\cdot \vec n_d=0,\ \ \Pi_2\to(p-p_2)\cdot\vec n_d=0$ we have

$$
p^* = \Pi_m\cap L_1\Rightarrow\cases{(S+\lambda\vec n_S-p_m)\cdot\vec n_m=0\\ \lambda = \frac{(p_m-S)\cdot\vec n_m}{\vec n_S\cdot\vec n_m}\\
p^* = S+\frac{(p_m-S)\cdot\vec n_m}{\vec n_S\cdot\vec n_m}\vec n_S
}
$$

now $\vec n_r = 2\vec n_m+\vec n_S$ and follows the determination of $R_1,\ R_2$ as the intersections $R_1 = L_2\cap\Pi_1,\ R_2 = L_2\cap \Pi_2$

so in the same procedure as to $p^*$ determination we have

$$
R_k = p^* +\frac{(p_k-p^*)\cdot \vec n_d}{\vec n_r\cdot\vec n_d}\vec n_r,\ \ k = \{1,2\}
$$

now assuming that $P_1, P_2$ are over the same line $L_P\to p = p_1 +\gamma \vec n_d$ we have

$$
R_k-P_k = p^* +\frac{(p_k-p^*)\cdot \vec n_d}{\vec n_r\cdot\vec n_d}\vec n_r-P_k,\ \ k = \{1,2\}
$$

with $p_2 = p_1 + \delta \vec n_d$ and $P_2 = P_1 + \delta \vec n_d$ (we can choose $p_{1,2} = P_{1,2}$)

Resuming, assuming that $\vec n_m = \vec n_m(\beta)$ and $\vec n_S = \vec n_S(\alpha)$ we need to know $S,p_m,\vec n_d, p_1,\delta$. Considering a plane problem, we have $8$ unknowns to determine from the following data $\{\alpha_j,\beta_j,\|R_{1j}-P_{1j}\|,\|R_{2j}-P_{2j}\|, j = 1,\cdots,n\}$

Answer (score 0):

If the reference for angle $\beta$ is parallel to $Y$-axis, and ray $P_{1,goal}-P_{2,goal}$ is also perpendicular to $Y$-axis then the angle between $n_d$ (perpendicular to the mirror) and $n_r$ is $\beta$. By Reflection Law, then the angle between $n_d$ and $n_s$ is also $\beta$. Then $\alpha=\pi/2-2\beta$

This means than the ray $n_s$ may *not* pass through point $S$.

If we know, for sure, that it does pass through $S$ then we need to move the mirror horizontally/vertically until it succeed.

To solve this problem we need more data:

- Relative position of mirror and point S
- Point of rotation of the
  mirror, related to the detectors.

Comment: When the goal is achieved, i.e. $n_r=P_{1,goal}−P_{2,goal}$, I do agree with your calculation that $\alpha=\pi/2−\beta$. However, I do not follow why in this case $S$ may not pass through $n_s$. Could you explain? Unfortunately, I do not have the data you ask for, however, iteratively one can find a solution, so I would argue that it must also be possible to calculate a solution (i.e. without iteration) only with the provided data.

Comment: @masteryoda436 If you have fixed the point of reflection $P*$ and the beam $n_s$ (you know its angle) how do you tell if $S$ lies in that beam?

Comment: @masteryoda436 If you can iteratively find a solution is because you have data (what I say is lacking) layout that satisfies the solution. I mean, starting from a layout that works and changing $\alpha, \beta$ you can restore $\alpha, \beta$ so as to it works again.

Comment: $P^*$ is not fixed but will move on the mirror depending on where the plane's center of rotation lies. Additionaly, I do not know the *absolute* angle of $n_s$, but only $\delta\alpha$ (the change in angle between successive measurements)

Comment: @masteryoda436 Do you have a mirror at hand? If yes, look through it towards a point, then fix your angle and move around. Eventually the "target" disapears from the mirror.

Comment: When using an iterative approach, I also just have $R_{1,k}$ and $R_{2,k}$ and the angles $\delta\alpha$ and $\delta\beta$ that I input. Essentially, this gives me a response function $R_{1,k}=f(\delta\alpha, \delta\beta)$ and $R_{2,k}=f(\delta\alpha, \delta\beta)$. Scanning through these responses for many angles will eventually yield a solution. I am quite certain that there must be a systematic method to this.

Comment: I understand that at some extreme angles, a target point may not be visible in the mirror's reflection anymore. However, I fail to see how this relates to your earlier comments. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122982/discussion-between-masteryoda436-and-ripi2).